# AppWidget in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appwidget

I would like to show AppWidget in Android Activity to make drap and drop facility and I would like to create some kind of floor plan with some widgets, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot readily "show AppWidget in Android Activity". An app widget has nothing whatsoever to do with "drap and drop facility".

Comment: Thank for the information. I would like to place Icons or Images or User Controls inside the activity by dragging and placing at some position on the activity. How can I do this?

Comment: @Girish: I recommend that you ask a new StackOverflow question, where you get rid of the "app widget" references, and explain in greater detail what it is you are trying to achieve with your drag and drop approach.